# LVTTL signal splitter - delay - combine circuit

Tags: digital-logic

Pulsed laser driver provides NIM logic level output for synchronization at the laser repetition rate (20 MHz)  https://www.nktphotonics.com/lasers-fibers/product/superk-evo-industrial-white-light-laser/

The NIM signal is converted via NIM to LVTTL converter. NIM2TTL converter has < 5 ps timing jitter.  After NIM2TTL the signal looks like this:

[image]

I am planning a circuit with following functionality:

SPLIT the LVTTL signal into 2 signals.
   DELAY one by 25 ns.
   COMBINE them together.

Combined signal (40 Mhz) will be used as a triggering signal for another laser so that the second laser emits pulse with some overlap to the pulse in the 40 MHz signal. Practically we shift the second laser trigger signal by picosecond delayer, +- 50 ps makes some noticeable difference in results, probably +- 100 ps would be okay. The circuit will be in room with stable temperature.

This is the circuit I have so far:

[image]

Considering the desired functionality I would have following questions.

Would be

1. PI6C49CB04BQ, *Low Skew, 1-TO-4 LVCMOS/LVTTL Fanout Buffer*  suitable as a IC to split the LVTTL signal into two signals?
   https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/PI6C49CB04BQ.pdf
2. DS1100LZ-25+ Delay Line : suitable as a fixed delay line? Not considering < 1ns jitter requirement, would be this IC suitable in principle?
   https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/256/DS1100L-1291925.pdf

Mouser website mentions logic family 74LS. Datasheet doesn't specify the maximum frequency.

https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/Maxim-Integrated/DS1100LZ-25%2b?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtcQMvy0tpsilNMExKZh%2FbYWt4YZpoWTXM%3D

Would 74LS logic family be capable of processing signal at 20 Mhz ?

3. 74ALVC32 Quad 2-input OR gate - be suitable as LVTTL combiner?
   https://www.mouser.at/datasheet/2/916/74ALVC32-1597313.pdf

I apologize for very broad question.

Question was edited to provide broader context. Initially the question was about how to split LVTTL signal. I kindly appreciate all your hints and advices.

Added information about NIM2TTL converter's timing jitter.

Comment: Show your proposed circuit and provide a hyper-link to the PDF (portable document format) data sheet of the proposed device.

Comment: "it comes from a laser": Well, a laser doesn't output pulses, so I think it comes from something like a sensor? Or do you mean a laser driver? We'll need a whole lot more info on where that signal comes from. Also, I don't think it's possible to recommend any way to keep jitter low, if you don't tell us what the jitter currently amounts to (e.g. you'd not win anything by building a system with RMS jitter of 200 fs if your signal currently has 1 ns of RMS jitter.)

Comment: I don't have the first hand measurement information about the timing jitter. Considering the NIM2TTL has < 5ps timing jitter and the fact the pulsed laser should provide very stable timing source I would say it's timing jitter is much less than of the NIM2TTL converter's.

Comment: The fanout buffer has a propagation delay of a few nanoseconds which will add a bit of uncertainty according to the current circuit.

Comment: I was thinking about it again and actually timing jitter up to 1 ns would be acceptable. 2-3 would still work.